# How to test custom async/await hook with react-hooks-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

I created a custom react hook that is supposed to handle all less important api requests, which i don't want to store in the redux state. Hook works fine but I have trouble testing it. My test setup is jest and enzyme, but I decided to give a try **react-hooks-testing-library** here as well.

What I have tried so far is to first mock fetch request with a **fetch-mock** library, what works fine. Next, i render hook with `renderHook` method, which comes from react-hooks-testing-library. Unfortunately, looks like I do not quite understand the `waitForNextUpdate` method.

This is how my hook looks like.

**useApi hook**

```
export function useApi<R, B = undefined>(
    path: string,
    body: B | undefined = undefined,
    method: HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET
): ResponseStatus<R> {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async (): Promise<void> => {
            setError(false);
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const result = await callApi(method, path, body);
                setResponse(result);
            } catch (errorResponse) {
                setError(errorResponse);
            }

            setIsLoading(false);
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [path, body, method]);

    return { response, isLoading, error };
}
```

Hook can take 3 different state combinations that I would like to test. Unfortunately, I have no idea how.

**Loading data:**

```
{ response: undefined, isLoading: true, error: false }
```

**Loaded data:**

```
{ response: R, isLoading: false, error: false }
```

**Error:**

```
{ response: undefined, isLoading: false, error: true }
```

This is how my test looks like at this moment:

```
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import { useApi } from './hooks';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

test('', async () => {
    fetchMock.mock('*', {
        returnedData: 'foo'
    });

    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useApi('/data-owners'));

    console.log(result.current);

    await waitForNextUpdate();

    console.log(result.current);
});
```

**callApi func**

```
/**
 * Method to call api.
 *
 * @param {HttpMethod} method - Request type.
 * @param {string} path - Restful endpoint route.
 * @param {any} body - Request body data.
 */
export const callApi = async (method: HttpMethod, path: string, body: any = null) => {
    // Sends api request
    const response = await sendRequest(method, path, body);
    // Checks response and parse to the object
    const resJson = response ? await response.json() : '';

    if (resJson.error) {
        // If message contains error, it will throw new Error with code passed in status property (e.g. 401)
        throw new Error(resJson.status);
    } else {
        // Else returns response
        return resJson;
    }
};
```

Comment: `react-hooks-testing-library` author here.  Your usage of `renderHook` and `waitForNextUpdate` look correct, so I think there is either a batching issue occuring or a  some other reason preventing the update from occurring.  What is the actual error you are seeing when the test fails and from your console logs?

Answer (score 1):

It's all right that you did. Now, you need use expect for test.

```
const value = {...}
expect(result.current).toEqual(value)
```